# excute rails server but got output of rails -h

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've followed [this article](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-ruby-on-rails/) to do this, but after I excuted `rails server`, he just gave me the output of `rails -h`, I have no idea about it, somebody help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you created any project yet? you have installed rails correctly. Now you have to create project. If you have created your project than do `cd myapp` and now run following command

```
rails s
```

It should work, I hope you already installed postgres as per tutorial, but if not no worry, following will still work using sqlite3

```
rails new newmyapp
```

It will show you screenflow activities. Now it finish just change directory to myapp using `cd newmyapp` and run following command

```
rails s
```

it will show your famous rails page.

Comment: it didn't work, I do create new project by excuting `rails new myapp`

Comment: here is the [screenshot](https://github.com/wqreytuk/wqreytuk.github.io/blob/master/qwe.png)

Comment: Well not sure where is issue, but your snapshot show very few lines as when you run `rails new myapp` command you will see many more lines, it will create many lines. Can you check your have git tools installed?

Comment: Why I need install git?

Comment: Oh wow well rails new commands initiate git repository for project, and there are many different uses of git in rails, but I thought it should give some error message about it. Any how please click on tick mark near answer to accept this as answer.